# parsing inputs to shell script on command line

Tags: bash, shell, unix, loops, scripting

I'm trying to assign everything else after strings to $@ but orange is also picked. I thought the shift will take as rest of the args but the output is picking orange too.

```
$ cat try.sh
#!/usr/bin/bash

str1="$1"
str2="$2"; shift

echo "$str1"
echo "$str2"

for i in "$@"
do
echo "rest are $i"
done

./try.sh apple orange 3 4 5
apple
orange
rest are orange
rest are 3
rest are 4
rest are 5
```

Comment: Type `help shift` in a bash session.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do shift twice to get rid of both apple and orange. a single shift will only shift off **one** parameter, no matter where in the code it is - it's NOT related to which parameter was last accessed/assigned from.

```
 str1="$1"
 str2="$2"; shift ; shift
```

or

```
 str1="$1"; shift
 str2="$1"; shift # Notice that due to prior shift, orange now is in $1, not $2
```

Comment: Or use `shift 2` -- specifying the number to shift is commonly used in script that employ `getopts`: after parsing options, you'd use `shift $((OPTIND-1))`